# how to escape from full screen mode in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have used this code to go full screen:

```
private void fullScreenPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    full = new JFrame();
    full.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    full.setUndecorated(true);
    full.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I run the program, the JFrame is stuck in the full-screen mode, and I can't close it when I press escape. Thus, I had to restart or log out of my computer to get back to normal screen again. I want the user to be able to close it by pressing the "escape button" or using other combinations. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `keyEventListener` for that, which disposes the frame if you have pressed escape. After that, it will not be usable again.

```
full.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
            full.dispose();
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that the frame needs to be focused, or else the event is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 KeyStroke k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
 int w = full.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
 dialog.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(e -> window.dispose(), k, w);
```